# Find out why a running process dies

Tags: python, process-management

I have a few processes that for some reason end when they shouldn't. How can I know from the process ID if it was killed automatically by the kernel or even by some other user?

Comment: The answer should be in the logs! What OS is this?

Comment: Debian 3.16.43-2 (2017-04-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Each process is a python script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678978/how-to-debug-python-script-that-is-crashing-python

Answer (score 2):

you should trace your process by `Strace` Commande :

```
strace -p <PID> -o <OUTPUT_FILE>
```

or

```
sudo strace -p <PID> -o <OUTPUT_FILE>
```

in **OUTPUT_FILE** you will find all Informations about the execution of your Python Script and you can have some information about what causes their ends.

Comment: My OS don't have that command. Is there any alternative? I'm using Debian 3.16.43-2 (2017-04-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Sorry, I end up installing it. Ok, thank you.